Dell Inspiron 3891 running Windows 11 dies at Grub launch screen
Dell Inspiron 3891 running Windows 11 refuses to boot into Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) from a bootable USB drive.  Dies at initial loading screen. There was supposed to be a Ubuntu update on August 29th to help with the problem but after downloading and reflashing the USB stick the problem persists.
I need information about Machine Owners Keys (MOK) and mokutil (i.e. where to get it and how to use it.) Any help would be appreciated.
Update: I've tried both with and without secure boot, with Secure Boot deployed or in Audit mode, with Custom key Mode Management Set to PK, etc. with Platform Trust Technology both off and on in various combinations. Same result. Tried the editing feature on the USB boot loader, but without the Linux kernel running it simply returns error 'code': Kernel not loaded. Last night I downloaded another Linux flavor, flashed and tried to boot again.  Got the same result. (Black screen of death as soon as a menu option was chosen -- in both regular and safe mode.) Note: Used same flashed USB stick to boot laptop after fail and reached the trial program without any problem.
Conclusion:
Whatever is happening, the problem doesn't lie with Linux, but with Dell Bios and/or Windows 11.
Not to worry; my backup machine is running Ubuntu and I WILL have Ubuntu on my main system, even if I have to trash the Dell and start with a clean machine. I'm done with Microsoft. (End of rant.)

The Machine Owner's Key (MOK) is used to self-sign third part kernel modules (like video drivers), so secure boot may be left enabled. If you don't have any such modules, you really don't need to have one. It's self generated, asks you for a pass phrase which you'll probably never have to use. mokutil is just a package which may be installed, but you probably don't need.

Thanks.  If required, where and how would such a key be used?  My choices are in BIOS or in Windows 11.  I've tried every combination of BIOS settings (i.e. Secure boot on or off, etc.) Same black screen at loading screen as soon as an option is chosen. Computer does not support legacy boot and the computer dies before a Linux Kernel can be loaded. USB stick boots other machines for install, so it's not the USB drive.  It's as if BIOS is blocking the boot.

Turn off Secure Boot, and the machine should no longer complain about unsigned kernel modules.  The only time i've see the MOK pass phrase request is at an install. sbsign or mokutil might let you enter the MOK from a running system, but no experience doing that.

Thank you again.  Tried both with and without secure boot, with Secure Boot deployed or in Audit mode, with Custom key Mode Management: Set to PK, with Platform Trust Technology both off and on in various combinations.  Same result. Tried the editing feature on the USB boot loader, but without the kernel running it simply returns error 'code': Kernel not loaded.
